# H1N1 Probability Problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> Suppose that the probability of being affected by H1N1 flu virus is
>   0.02, the probability of those who regularly wash their hands among those affected by the H1N1 virus is known as 0.3, In general, if the
>   probability of people who washing their hands regularly between the
>   whole people (whether they affected or not by the virus) is 0.6, Find
>   the possibility of those who regularly wash their hands to be affected
>   by the virus.

---

### Proposed Solution:

```
lets A be the event of people who affected with H1N1 virus
and  B be the event of people who regularly washing their hands
```

**In this case**

```
P(A) = 0.02
P(A and B) = 0.3
P(B) = 0.6
P(A|B) = ?
```

**Rule:**

```
P(A|B) = P(A and B) / P(B)
       =       0.3 / 0.6 = 0.5
```

---

### Well, my question is:

**Are my assumptions and the proposed solution right or not? if not please correct my answer.**


Thanks in advance.
:)

Comment: $0.3$ divided by $0.6$ is not $0.18$.

Comment: The chance of $A$ and $B$ happening together is not $0.3$. This should already become apparent from the fact that the chance of $A$ happening individually is only $0.02$. It's $P(B | A) = 0.3$ which you can derive from the information given.

Comment: The problem is very poorly phrased. In particular,  I don't understand what "the probability of those who regularly wash their hands among those affected by the H1N1 virus is known as 0.3" means.  I can think of a few possible interpretations.  Either $P(A\cap B)=.3$ or $P(A\,|\,B)=.3$ or $P(B\,|\,A)=.3$

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof Thanks for your correction, I did change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood your problem, you should use Bayes formula:
$$
P(infect|wash) = \frac{P(wash|infect)P(infect)}{P(wash)}
$$
where $P(infect) = 0.02, P(wash)=0.6, P(wash|infect) = 0.3$.

Comment: Thanks bro, actually I don't know the final result, how could i assure from the answer, is there any way or method?